# Pass static value to urls.py python

Tags: python, django

i wonder if I could possible pass a string in urls.py such as:

"Pending"

```
url(r'^create/(?P<userName>[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/Pending$', views.create, name='create')
```

and in views. it would be.

```
def create(request, userName, Status):
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes its possible as karthikr's answer shows... but is it really needed? I'm guessing you can derive the status from the user in which case a `/status` might be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Here is one regex pattern to help you achieve it

```
url(r'^create/(?P<userName>[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/(?P<Status>Pending|Completed)$', views.create, name='create')
```

Here, `Status` parameter of the view would have the accepted regex value - `Pending` in your example. the `Completed` was an example to extend valid acceptable values